# Choosing database paradigm

Tags: sql, database-design, architecture, nosql

Say your data is fairly relational in nature, but the scale of your application has outgrown the performance ability of your database... Given that most NoSQL solutions out there seem to promise much better performance (I'm working on a real-time content recommendation engine), I'm looking at alternatives. I can think of ways to smack my data model around so it could be represented as documents, graphs, or even simple/abusive key-value pairs...

**But where is the [complexity vs performance] trade-off worth while/smart??** Does it sound reasonable to increase the complexity of the application so that we can use a document-oriented database in the hopes that performance will increase?

**What are some proven principles/rules of thumb to guide the design decisions in such a situation?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend [Fighting the NoSQL mindset](http://dennisforbes.ca/index.php/2010/03/24/the-impact-of-ssds-on-database-performance-and-the-performance-paradox-of-data-explodification/) and [NoNoSQL](http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2010/03/nonosql.html)

Neither of these are biased towards traditional RDBMS despite their titles, they both give pretty decent perspectives on the tradeoffs. This topic has raged for years all over the internet but quality articles are hard to pick out of the noise. Good luck!

edit: almost forgot [NoSQL data modeling techniques](http://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)